# Add hyperlink to PNG inside flexdashboard

Tags: html, r, hyperlink, png, flexdashboard

I would like to add a hyperlink function to a PNG I have added to my flexdashboard.
I've managed to add a hyperlink to a text as shown in the code below (in the first section), but I would like to add it to the PNG icon I have added in the second section of my code

````
---
title: "PNG Hyperlink"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

# Homepage

## Column {data-width=500}

### Introduction
<font size = "5">Please read user manual before exploring this dashboard. You can find user manual by clicking <a href="file:///C:/Users/Filip/Desktop/Dashboard%20guide.htm" target=_blank>here</a></font><br><br><br>

### Introduction 2
<font size = "5">Please read user manual before exploring this dashboard. You can find user manual by clicking the following icon</font><br><br><br>
```{r}
knitr::include_graphics("document-icon.png")
```
````

Additionally, it would be great if someone knows how to make this picture smaller and wrap text arround it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue by working with the code following `@samarmohan` input.
Here is the code

````
### Introduction 2
<font size = "5">Please read user manual before exploring this dashboard. You can find user manual by clicking the following icon</font><br><br><br>
<a href="file:///C:/Users/Filip/Desktop/Dashboard%20guide.htm" target=_blank><center>
```{r dpi=10}
knitr::include_graphics("document-icon.png")
```
</center></a>
````

I have added `href` in order to add hyperlink to the icon and make the icon smaller using `dpi =` inside the {r} box

Answer (score 1):

Add an `href` attribute.
This should work